# How to track newly added record to NDB datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I've used the following code before:

```
def add_movie(movie_id, title, picture, description):
    movie = Movies(
        id=movie_id,
        title=title,
        picture=picture,
        description=description
        )
    movie.put()
```

but it didn't allow me know if movie was added as new record or if existing movie was update. So, I've changed the code to the following:

```
def add_movie(movie_id, title, picture, description):
    newly_added = True
    movie = Movies.get_by_id(movie_id)
    if movie:
        newly_added = False
    movie.id = movie_id
    movie.title = title
    movie.picture = picture
    movie.description = description
    movie.put()
    return newly_added
```

But looks like it will get movie first and only after that will update it. So 2 requests to datastore instead of 1.

Is there any other way to do the same?
Or, am I wrong and both approaches are the same from performance perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no other way around it.

This will impact the performance due to additional `get` request, but 'get' is quite fast [and cheap](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costshttp://), so do not worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

As @Peter said: the get operations is very cheap and I wouldn't worry about it, but you can still store the movie id in the memcache and do a primarily check if its there, if its there then the movie is not new, if its not there check the datastore.